# Understanding how to derive the differential cross-section formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

I am studying how to derive the cross section out of S-matrix elements from the beautiful book *Quantum Field Theory* by Mandl and Shaw (second edition; chapter 8, section 8.1) and there are several steps I do not get.

We first consider two particles (they may be either leptons or photons) with initial (i.e. before collision) four momentum $p_i = (E_i, \mathbf p_i)$, $i=1,2$. These two collide and produce $N$ final particles with momentum $p'_f = (E'_f, \mathbf p'_f)$, $f=1,...,N$. In this post we assume that initial and final particles are in definite polarization states.

I learned in the previous chapter of the book that the S-matrix elements can be written as

$$\langle f| S |i \rangle = \delta_{fi} + \Big[ (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (P_f-P_i) \Pi_e \Big(\frac{m}{VE}\Big)^{1/2}\Pi_e \Big(\frac{1}{2V \omega}\Big)^{1/2} \Big] \mathscr{M} \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Where the e attached to the products stands for external fermions and photons.

In our case $(1)$ becomes

$$S_{fi} = \delta_{fi} + (2 \pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \Pi_i \Big(\frac{1}{2V E_i}\Big)^{1/2} \Pi_f \Big(\frac{1}{2V E'_f}\Big)^{1/2}\Pi_l (2m_l)^{1/2}\mathscr{M} \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Where $l$ runs over all external leptons involved in the collision.

Eq. $(2)$ applies to an infinite time interval (i.e $T \rightarrow \infty$) and an infinite volume (i.e $V \rightarrow \infty$).

For finite intervals we'd get the exact same as Eq. $(2)$ but $(2 \pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i)$ being replaced by $\delta_{TV} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i)$, as

$$(2 \pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) = lim_{T \rightarrow \infty, \ V \rightarrow \infty} \delta_{TV} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \ \ \ \ (3)$$

In deriving the cross section we better take $V$ and $T$ to be finite. In such a case the transition probability per unit time becomes

$$w=|S_{fi}|^2/T \ \ \ \ (4)$$

We notice that $|S_{fi}|^2$ means we have to deal with $\Big( \delta_{TV} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \Big)^2$, which equals to the following

$$\Big( \delta_{TV} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \Big)^2 = TV (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \ \ \ \ (5)$$

With errors which tend to zero as $T \rightarrow \infty$ and $V \rightarrow \infty$. Once we know this $(4)$ becomes

$$w=V(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}  (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \Pi_i \Big(\frac{1}{2V E_i}\Big)^{1/2} \Pi_f \Big(\frac{1}{2V E'_f}\Big)^{1/2} \Pi_l (2m_l)^{1/2} |\mathscr{M}|^2 \ \ \ \ (6)$$

Eq. $(6)$ is the transition rate to one definite final state.

If we wish to obtain the transition rate to a group of final states with momentum in the interval $(\mathbf p'_f, \mathbf p'_f +d\mathbf p'_f)$, $f=1,...,N$, we have to multiply $w$ by the number of these states, which is

$$\Pi_f \Big(\frac{V d^3 \mathbf p'_f}{(2\pi)^3}\Big)$$

The differential cross section is the transition rate into this group of final states for one scattering center and unit incident flux (which is also known as luminosity; I've read that particle physicists use more the latter term). With our choice of normalization for the states, the volume V contains one scattering center and the incident flux is $\frac{v_{rel}}{V}$, where $v_{rel}$ is the relative velocity of the colliding particles.

At this point we have everything to set up the equation for the differential cross section

$$d \sigma = w \frac{V}{v_{rel}} \Pi_f \Big(\frac{V d^3 \mathbf p'_f}{(2\pi)^3}\Big) \ \ \ \ (7)$$

Plugging $(6)$ into $(7)$ we get

$$d \sigma = (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}  (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i) \frac{1}{4 E_1 E_2 v_{rel}} \Pi_l (2m_l) \Pi_f \Big(\frac{d^3 \mathbf p'_f}{(2\pi)^3 2 E'_f}\Big) |\mathscr{M}|^2$$

**My questions are:**

1) I do not see why $(2)$ corresponds to the limit of an infinite time interval and an infinite volume.

2) I do not understand why we have to replace $(2 \pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i)$ by $\delta_{TV} (\sum p'_f - \sum p_i)$. Besides, I do not understand equation $(3)$.

3) I do not see how to get equation $(5)$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Great question and I look forward to see it answered. Could you perhaps tell me how you input all those eqs.? Did you use some GUI or special purpose program?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I used noting special, just regular $\LaTeX$ commands.

Comment: Thank you JD_PM :-)